# ASK: Generate positive values only in Normal Distribution (rnorm)

Tags: r

Is it possible to condition a rnorm function? For example, I want to include upper/lower limits for a normally distributed set (from 1 to 100) and all values are integers (suppose it describes a person's age). In that case, how does the code look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a package called `truncnorm`, that has some functions to use a **Truncated Normal Distribution**.

```
#install.packages("truncnorm")
library(truncnorm)

x <- rtruncnorm(n = 1000,a = 1,b = 100,mean = 50,sd = 5)

plot(density(x))
```

[image]

To make them integers, you can use `round`

```
y <- round(x)

plot(density(y))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! May I ask is this possible to set the lower limit but ignore the upper limit? also, is there any way I can pre-condition the value to be integers instead of rounding? (for example if the variables describe a rating of 1-10) Many thanks!!

Comment: To ignore the upper limit just don't set a number for `b`, it will use `Inf` as the default.

For the round question, if you want to simulate a discrete cenario, maybe selecting another distribution is better choice.